# SQL Server 2008 and SRRS - Convert timestamp (in BIGINT format) from Table and placing in Report in Date/Time format

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am very inexperienced with SQL and SSRS - my requirement is to select timestampped data from my SQL database table(18 digit bigint) and display in date/time format in reports[Picture of Report Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zpwe.png)
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is for helping out where people get stuck after they have a tangible attempt to the problem. I suggest you do something, make some sort of try, and only if/when you get stuck you publish what you have and clearly identify what has got you scratching your head.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this is SSRS you have to create a function for this. If you were me I would rather do this is sql query.

I'm not an expert on sql but here I did my best to help you. Try this:

```
DECLARE @TickValue BIGINT
DECLARE @Days FLOAT

SET @TickValue = 636016587648860000 
SET @Days = @TickValue * POWER(10.00000000000,-7) / 60 / 60 / 24


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d, Cast(@Days As int), Cast('0001-01-01' As DATE)),101)
+ ' ' + FORMAT(Cast((@Days - FLOOR(@Days)) As DateTime),'hh:mm')
```

OUTPUT:

```
06/16/2016 07:26
```

- I used one of your example from your screenshot as reference for my answer, I'm not actually sure this is the best approach or this doesn't have a flow though.